# What is the difference between (char*) and char*?

Tags: c++

in the line: `((string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);` Why use `(char*)` or `(string*)` as opposed to `char*` or `string`? Trying to use `char*` or `string`results in an error Also, what does the operator `->` do? It seems like it is just taking the place of `str.append(var, pos);`

Comment: With respect, questions like "what does `->` do?" are best answered by reading any [introductory book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(string*) is a cast to pointer to string and string is a class string.
(char*) is a cast to pointer to char and char* is a pointer to char.
the -> operator accesses the attributes or methods of a pointer to a class